# MySQL: Why is does escaping not working in the LIKE operator?

Tags: mysql, escaping, sql-like

I'm experimenting with pattern matching strings in MySQL 8.0:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar VARCHAR(250));

INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES ('\%');
```

As an exercise, I'd like to write a specific query using `LIKE` that returns rows that are "like the literal `\%`". *(I know this is should actually be done with `=` comparison but this is an exercise)*

1. As `%` is a wildcard character, I cannot simply use:

   `` SELECT * from `foo` WHERE `bar` LIKE '\%'; ``
2. When I try to escape using the default escape character `\` it also fails:

   `` SELECT * from `foo` WHERE `bar` LIKE '\\%'; ``
3. And likewise when I tryin to use the `ESCAPE` keyword to define a non-default escape character:

   `` SELECT * from `foo` WHERE `bar` LIKE '\|%' ESCAPE '|'; ``

**Why do queries 2 and 3 not work for me?**

Comment: Your client code (PHP? Java? ...) might be removing backslashes, so you might need to double them up!

Answer (score 1):

three is simple.

% is not a wildcard is t simply a character like every character else

```
SELECT * from `foo` WHERE `bar` LIKE '\%' ESCAPE '|';
```

Works just fine

The second works too.

But you need to

```
SELECT * from `foo` WHERE `bar` LIKE '\\\%';
```

I remember You have to escape the escape and the wildcard!